# How to translate ViewModel to Canvas in MVVM and WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am new to WPF and MVVM, and would appreciate help with the following problem.

I want to create an application in which a user specifies – through a dialog - how he would like to layout N number of chart objects on a page, and the application shows him this layout on a canvas.  When satisfied with the layout he sees in the canvas, the user persists it for later use.

All chart objects can be visualized as rectangles.  User can also define a header, which too is a rectangle.

A typical layout could be the header at the top of the page, below which are three charts side-by-side. User would be able to specify this layout as well as dimensions and location of each child in a dialog, and then hit the ‘Apply’ button expecting to see this specification in graphical form on the canvas.

In my view model  I would have a tree where the parent is the canvas, having one child of type header, and 3 children of chart type.

The user might not like what he sees, and make changes in the dialog which would then effect changes in the view model.

I kind of understand the View-ViewModel interaction between the dialog and the view model.  But don’t know how to implement the Canvas-ViewModel interaction. Meaning that when the user requests in the dialog say a header rectangle of a given size at a given coordinate, I know how to add that header object in the tree in the view model, but I do not know how to then update the canvas from the ViewModel's tree. How would the canvas get drawn to reflect the object tree in the viewmodel, and then get re-drawn each time the viewmodel changes (as a result of user's interaction with the dialog)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You shouldn't store graphical settings such as size and coordinates of your controls in your viewModel.

If I were you I would approch this a bit differently.

In the `View`, Use [DragAndDrop](http://wpftutorial.net/DragAndDrop.html) operations on the canvas to let the user change the location of the charts and header.

You can use [`GridSplitter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff382751%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) to make them user-resizable

Then, when user hits `Apply`, Save the canvas object using [XamlWriter.Save](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms590450.aspx) method

When you need it for later use, load it using [XamlReader.Load](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms590398.aspx) method

In your `ViewModel` have a command that gets the canvas as a parameter and handles the `Save` operation.

### Example

view:

```
<Canvas x:Name="mainCanvas">
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="My Header ..."/>

            <!-- Charts goes here .... -->

            <Button Content="Apply">
                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ApplyCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=mainCanvas}"/>
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
            </Button>
        </StackPanel>
</Canvas>
```

view model:

```
public class MainWindowViewModel
{
    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        ApplyCommand = new DelegateCommand<Canvas>(canvas =>
            {
                string userLayout = XamlWriter.Save(canvas);

                // save userLayout for later use ...
            });
    }

    public DelegateCommand<Canvas> ApplyCommand { get; set; }
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

One option is to add the viewmodels to a collection, and then bind those to an ItemsControl. If you provide the appropriate datatemplates in the XAML, the views are automatically bound to the data. The Itemscontrol I have looks like this:

```
    <ItemsControl x:Name="WorksetPresenter"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=RootWindow, Path=TableauItems}"
                  >
        <ItemsControl.Resources>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:AnalysisViewModel}">
                 <wg:AnalysisView DataContext="{Binding DescriptiveAnalysis}"/>
            </DataTemplate>

        <!-- more datatemplates for more view/viewmodel pairs --> 

        </ItemsControl.Resources>

        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Canvas />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    </ItemsControl>
```

TableauItems is an ObservableCollection<>. As soon as an ViewModel is added to the collection, it is rendered on the Canvas according to the View specified in the datatemplate. For positioning you can use e.g. the Canvas.Left and Canvas.Top properties (mind the alignment!), or a rendertransform.

Comment: In the above example, where is the geometry of the shape that is to be drawn in Canvas decided? Say you want to render the data in a circle, or inside an ellipse, or a rectangle...... where do you specify this shape geometry? thanks

Comment: That will be in your View. If you want an ellipse, do <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:AnalysisViewModel}"> <Ellipse Width="10" Height="10" Fill ="Black"/></Datatemplate> , but if the view is more complex, I usually make that a separate UserControl, and then bind the datacontext to the viewmodel as in the codefragment.

Answer (score 0):

If the application specifically deals with changes in layout and layout information is the data you are presenting, then putting layout information in your view model is certainly appropriate. However, simple presentation information does not belong in your view model.

For that you need a different solution. Consider this.
If I need to locate view model template location on screen, how do I do it? My view model cannot know about the visual tree! Bugger. To solve this, I tag elements with attached properties and use a custom layout behavior or control to query the attached properties.

This is very similar to how jQuery allows a javascript programmer to grab DOM elements from a web page.